# Яндекс карты - событие на зум

Tags: jquery, javascript

Как на яндекс картах навесить событие на зум? например, как [тут](http://api.yandex.ru/maps/tools/getlonglat/)

жмем на плюсик, у нас берется значение зума, и если, допустим, у нас значение зума больше десяти то, допустим, сделать `alert('Жмак жмак');`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На карту нужно повесить событие `boundschange`. Код взят из примера в [документации](http://api.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.x/ref/reference/Map.xml#event-boundschange).

```
map.events.add('boundschange', function (event) {
    if (event.get('newZoom') != event.get('oldZoom')) {
        alert('Уровень масштабирования изменился');
    }
});
```